# Provisioning profile is downloaded but cannot choose

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile

I have a provisioning profile, which allows for Push Notifications and I spent a long time working getting it right. I finally figured it all out and push notifications work! Now I am updating the same app for some reason I cannot choose the right profile. When I choose a profile to submit with, I cannot pick the right profile
[image]

But here it is when I click on accounts in Xcode!

[image]

It's INSchoolLawPushNotificationsProduction.

I have found the file and double clicked it, dragged it onto Xcode on the dock, everything. I have tried other Xcode Projects, nothing except the profiles in the first image are showing up! What do I do?

Comment: Might possible you have multiple profiles installed, or app id doesn't match. Download [iPhone Configuration Utitlity](http://iphone-configuration-utility.soft32.com/mac/), and delete all profiles, install again. It should fix.

Answer (score 0):

Please double check the followings

1. Check if your identifier are same in profile and in app.
2. Make sure you select the profile in settings also select the right certificate.
   [image]
3. When you are going to upload you choose the same account which you used for the to create profiles and certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Your production provisioning profile has expired (it did so on 9/15/2015).  You cannot use an expired profile.

Log back into the the developer site and create a new distribution profile.

Also, you're developer profiles will expire in a couple of months - may as well create new versions of those as well.

Comment: Okay. If I create a new distribution profile, will I also have to go through the creation of a new certificate signing request and all that stuff?

Comment: No, as long as the certificate hasn't expired and you haven't revoked it, you simply need to create a new profile for the app ID of the app you want to build.